# After minting 10,000 NFTs, do you list them for sale one by one? If so, then how long does it take to finish listing all of them?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, transactions, nft

After minting 10,000 NFTs, do you list them for sale one by one? If so, then how long does it take to finish listing all of them?

Comment: Hello! This is an opinion-based question (and stack exchange isn't for opinion-based questions), and it might be better on something like Reddit. There isn't a single canonical answer to this, and it'll likely change rapidly as the ecosystem evolves.

Answer (score 1):

If Your NFT follows ERC721/ERC1155. You can find your NFTs directly on [Opensea](https://opensea.io/) or Rarrible or any other NFT marketplace explorer. So, you dont have to list them.

How to search your NFTs on marketplace?

Just search your Smart Contract Address on opensea, and you will se your collection.

If you are using wallet address which deployed the Smart Contrct, you can edit few things about your collection.

Note - Your NFT Smart Contract must have inherited ERC721/ERC1155.

i.e. This is [Smart Contract](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xbff1E0a8fFfb8DE4EC2812f3145B1D1A32A0E68d#code) and this is [Collection](https://testnets.opensea.io/collection/taygennft)

Comment: I mean how long does it take to price all of those NFTs?

Answer (score 0):

You list the collection for sale. The address of the collection remains the same what changes is the token ID.